# Area of Questionably Generated Manifold

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I might not possess the language to ask this question, but I'm going to try anyway.

Consider a path **c**(*t*) : $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  Let **c**'(*t*) denote the tangent vector of the path **c**(*t*).  Can we "stitch" together the tangent vectors given by evaluating **c**'(*t*) at each point along the path such that a smooth manifold is generated?  Does this only work for simply connected closed paths?  Rather, what are the constraints for a path that can potentially serve as a substructure for such a manifold?  Can we meaningfully evaluate the area of this manifold?  Is this manifold 1-dimensional?  Are such manifolds unique to their paths?  Can there exist a manifold for one orientation of the path but not the other?  What properties would need to hold for the reverse orientation to generate a manifold of equivalent area to the standard orientation's manifold?  How can we classify this object?  Are there any applications for this?

I will award the answer to whoever covers each question and provides both an interesting example of a path and a counterexample to the idea that any path can have such a manifold.

I guess the simplest example of a substructure would be **c**(*$\theta$*) : $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by **c**(*$\theta$*) = < $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$ >.  Would the area of the manifold generated be acquired using the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{\sqrt2} rdrd\theta$  ?  I used intuition about the boundary and basic geometry to obtain this result.

I may revise my questions after I get some responses and learn better language to approach this problem with.

Comment: By area, I thought you were meant to talk about surfaces, but what you gave is actually a curve?

Comment: I meant to specify an example of a substructure.  The way I'm defining substructure, it is a curve that you can use to construct a manifold by essentially filling space with all of the tangent vectors and then integrating over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for any smooth manifold, $M$ and $p \in M$ we can consider the tangent space to $M$ at $p$, denoted $T_p M$. This is a real vector space with dimension equal to the dimension of $M$. You can consider the space of all tangent spaces of $M$ which is called the tangent bundle of $M$. A point of the tangent bundle of $M$ is a pair, a point $p$ of $M$ and a vector in $T_p M$. If $M$ is $n$-dimensional, then the tangent bundle, usually denoted $TM$ is $2n$ dimensional. It is difficult to visualize in general, but for $S^1$, we have the $TS^1$ is a cylinder, for example.

The object you're describing can be thought of as a submanifold of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb R^n$, and since we can canonically identify this with $\mathbb R^{2n}$, which has a canonical Riemannian metric, we can make sense of the area of this. If anyone can add anything more useful, that'd be great, because I'm not sure how useful this is for OP.

Comment: Of course, I knew I'd mess something up.

Comment: Wouldn't $TS^1$ be the plane it resides in?

Comment: For each point of $S^1$ you get a copy of $\mathbb R$. If we think of them as being perpendicular to our copy of $S^1 \in \mathbb R^{2}$, we see it is a cylinder. I was a little vague in my description, the details should make it clear. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle